# Como excluir a última linha da tabela?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Id.</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Qtd.</th>
        <th>Unitário</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> 1 </th>
      <td> 10</td>
      <td> 20</td>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> 30 </td>
      <td> 300 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> 2 </th>
      <td> 40</td>
      <td> 50</td>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> 60 </td>
      <td> 600 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn" 
  id="btnexcluirultima">ExcluirUltimaLinha</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#btnexcluirultima").on('click', function(){
    //Excluir a ultima linha da tabela
    $(".table td").closest('td').remove();
  });
```

Eu preciso apenas excluir a ultima linha da tabela! Como eu faço, por gentileza, da forma que fiz, exclui todas as linhas da tabela...o que fiz de errado, **desde já, obrigado!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o seletor `:last`. Para excluir uma linha você seleciona `tr`, e não `td`:

```js
$("#btnexcluirultima").on('click', function(){
    //Excluir a ultima linha da tabela
    $(".table tr:last").remove();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Id.</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Qtd.</th>
        <th>Unitário</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> 1 </th>
      <td> 10</td>
      <td> 20</td>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> 30 </td>
      <td> 300 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> 2 </th>
      <td> 40</td>
      <td> 50</td>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> 60 </td>
      <td> 600 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn" 
  id="btnexcluirultima">ExcluirUltimaLinha</button>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda! Já adptei o código aqui e resolveu meus problemas! Obrigado *dvd*, eu estou esperando os 10 minutos restantes para marcar sua resposta.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {

    $('#btnexcluirultima').on('click', function () {
        var trs = $('.table').find('tr');

        if (trs.length > 1)
          trs.last().remove();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Id.</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Qtd.</th>
        <th>Unitário</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> 1 </th>
      <td> 10</td>
      <td> 20</td>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> 30 </td>
      <td> 300 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> 2 </th>
      <td> 40</td>
      <td> 50</td>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> 60 </td>
      <td> 600 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn" 
  id="btnexcluirultima">ExcluirUltimaLinha</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Marcelo, adaptei o código verificador se tem linhas para remover antes de executar a função. Obrigado! Já postei como melhor resposta a anterior, mas deu um voto para você porque é justo e vc me ajudou muito. Obrigado!